# Reading GET/POST requests from the Browser on JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to find a way of reading GET/POST requests from the WEB browser(Network) and retrieve the information like Status, Domain, Size, IP and the most important Timeline.

The main purpose of this is to measure requests count after each action on the WEB page and their execution time. Also this will help me to know if any requests(AJAX/JavaScript) are executing before I want to perform any actions on the WEB page.

Could you please help me with solution?

Comment: I am not sure if you're 100% clear here so let me just ask a few questions - did you have a look at the HttpServletRequest you are using (because you say you are reading the requests on Java this means that you are using Java on the backend)? Or do you confuse Java and JavaScript here?

Comment: I am creating test cases using Selenium framework on Java, thus I am not using any HttpServletRequest. I am doing BlackBox testing for a web application, so I need to track which GET or POST requests were sent to the server and measure response time after I performed some actions (click, select etc.) from the Browser.

Comment: Did you take a look at [browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)?

Comment: This is just collects the Browser metrics in the background and provide the report of the information I need in the real time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to tie yourself to a particular browser (via plugins or particular dev toolbars), need to capture responses from interactive user events (i.e. via simulated use of a website in a real browser, not dynamically created HTTP calls), and need to automate this, then a proxy server is the way to go.

Something like [Browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) can be set up as a [proxy for all Selenium](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) traffic. It can capture the entire content of all requests and responses, and let you generate you a (cross-browser) [HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) that you can then persist, visualise, or query via an API.

Obviously you could automate this, schedule the Selenium test runs, and either produce your own custom metrics with your own Java code; pipe the HAR into a JSON-savvy database for querying (say Elasticsearch) and visualisation, or just save the HARs for offline querying and diffing.

Some example code from the [tests](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/browsermob-core/src/test/java/net/lightbody/bmp/proxy/HarTest.java):

```
[...]
proxy.newHar("Test");

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getLocalServerHostnameAndPort() + "/a.txt?foo=bar&a=1%262");
client.execute(get);

Har har = proxy.getHar();
HarLog log = har.getLog();

List<HarEntry> entries = log.getEntries();

HarEntry entry = entries.get(0);
HarRequest req = entry.getRequest();
[...]
```

Alternatively you can visualise the output by obtaining the HAR in string form and pasting into http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/. That should give you something that looks very similar to the Network tab, but in a format that's easier to export, screenshot, and print.

Answer (score 0):

1. Chrome comes with devtools by itself. Just hit 'F12'.
   https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
2. Postman, it's useful for testing web services and API
   https://www.getpostman.com/